# hql select table records from many to one relationship tables

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I've these three tables.

```
UserTrackRecord -> id, profile_id(fk), object_profile_id(int)
Profile and -> id
ProfilePersonalInfo-> id, profile_id(fk), firstname, lastname
```

The profile_id and object_profile_id are for the purpose that when somebody sends me a request of friendship, the object_profile_id is my profile id and the foreign key is the profile id of the sender.

one profile has many usertrackrecords.
one profile has one profilepersonalinfo (There are two more tables just like profilepersonalinfo which are basicinfo and backgroundinfo having profileid as fk).

I've got my own profile id(objecct_profile_id) say 1. Now, I wanna get the firstname, lastname of the request sender and information from the other two tables as well.

The sql query which i made is

```
select utr.profile_profile_id, ppi.dob, ppi.first_name, ppi.last_name, "
                + "pbi.religion, pbi.city_birth, pbi.country_birth from "
                + "user_track_record utr "
                + "inner join profile_personnel_info ppi on ppi.profile_profile_id=utr.profile_profile_id "
                + "inner join profile_background_info pbi on pbi.profile_profile_id=utr.profile_profile_id "
                + "where utr.object_profile_id=1
```

which is working fine.

In hql, when i simplified my query at most, it became

```
Select * from UserTrackRecord utr inner join ProfilePersonalInfo ppi
```

but id didn't work and it gave me the outer or full join must be followed by path expression query exception.

I posted the same question before, but somebody de-voted it :( so i did some more R&D but didn't find a solution.

Comment: Your post is not directly linked to a JSF, I removed that tag and add Java instead.

Comment: HQL works with entities. Instead of describing your tables, show us the entities and their associations, and tell us what you want to return from the query, in terms of these entities.

Answer (score 0):

I understand why this was voted down previously. Please go thru the hibernate documentation before posting the question.

As mentioned above hibernate works with entities, you need to mention an alias when you are joining tables in hibernate.

```
Select utr from UserTrackRecord utr inner join utr.profilePersonalInfo ppi and so on......
```

Since you have not provided your entities, I am assuming that UserTrackRecord is having an attribute called profilePersonalInfo which is of Type ProfilePersonalInfo. If not then please go thru Hibernate associations.